# How reversing the edges of the graph not altering the original conditions?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, data-structures, connected-components

I was going through the [main idea](https://usaco.guide/problems/cses-1682-flight-routes-check/solution#:%7E:text=Let%27s%20say,answer%20is%20%22YES%22.) of solution to this [problem](https://cses.fi/problemset/task/1682). I could not assimilate the idea of reversing the edges and then using that graph to check if node 1 is reachable from all others.

How come reversing the graph not affect the original conditions and is applicable to be used for the intended purpose? Is this graph not entirely different?

Is there some explaination which is **obvious** with respect to the problem? What exactly is happening here? Any explaination would be helpful. TIA.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the problem and its solution that needs clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Fix some vertex $u$. Consider the following observations:

- A path that ends at vertex $u$, which originates from some other vertex $v$ will be a path that originates from $u$ and ends at $v$ in the reversed graph.
- You can test if a vertex $u$ reaches all other vertices $v$ via DFS starting at $u$ in the original graph.
- You can test if all other vertices $v$ can reach $u$ via DFS starting at $u$ in the reversed graph
- If all vertices can be reached by $u$ and all vertices can reach $u$ then all pairs of vertices are reachable from each other since any vertex can reach any other vertex by passing through $u$.